# How do I centre a <button> and issue with coding

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone could help me with something that I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to centre this `<button>`.

Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/EZLOdP).

Below is my HTML/CSS coding.

```
 <button class="button" href="#">Contact Us</button>

.button {
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:4px;
  background-color:#f4511e;
  border:none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px;
  width:125px;
  transition:all 0.5s;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Furthermore, where has my arrow gone? The arrow on the page isn't the one I want it to be. Here is the coding that I inputted into my codepen but the arrow doesn't show. Could the arrowing currently displayed on my codepen could it be blocking it? Does the javascript coding still work with the new arrow?

Below is the HTML/CSS coding of the arrow I want to be shown. (if the colour of the arrow is the issue I tried changing it and still couldn't be seen.)

```
<div id="arrow"></div>    
#arrow {
    height: 50px;
    width: 112px;
  color: white;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    margin: 100px;
    font-size: 74pt;
    transform: rotateX(63deg) rotate(90deg);
}`
```

Kind Regards,

Liam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to center the `button`, so if you update its rule it will

```
.button {
  display:block;                 /*  changed  */
  margin: 0 auto;                /*  added    */
  border-radius:4px;
  background-color:#f4511e;
  border:none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px;
  width:125px;
  transition:all 0.5s;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Your *arrow* will show if you give it a border, like this

```
#arrow {
    height: 50px;
    width: 112px;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid red;      /*  added     */
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    margin: 100px;
    font-size: 74pt;
    transform: rotate(63deg);   /*  changed   */
}
```

[**Updated codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oByzXe)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! Could you do me a favour please since I don't know how to do it? You see the white square can you replace it with the red arrow so it's it that position? Will the javascript still work with it?

Comment: @LiamDocherty Like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oByzXe ... I moved the `#arrow` css code to the `.next` rule and deleted the `#arrow` div from the markup

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to center the button? If so, you can do so by adding the following to the .button CSS config:

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
}
```

As for the arrow, if you need a custom cursor, easiest would be to produce an image and add it to CSS:

```
div {
    cursor: url(YOUR_IMAGE_URL), auto;
}
```